# Bootstrap dropdown-menu does'nt open

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

i imported these:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And here is the html code for the dropdown:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Blog_Flask</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="/">Anasayfa</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="/about">Hakkımızda</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end">
            
            {% if session['logged_in'] %}
            
            
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{ session["name"] }}</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a href="/dashboard" class="dropdown-item">Kontrol Paneli</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/logout" class="dropdown-item">Çıkış Yap</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <p style="display: inline;" class="nav-link disable"> olarak giriş yaptınız.</p>
                </li>
                

            {% else %}
            
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" style="display:inline;" href="/login">Giriş Yap</a><p style="display:inline; color:white;">/</p><a class="nav-link active" style="display:inline;" href="/register">Kayıt Ol</a>
                </li>
            
            {% endif %}

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But the drop-down doesn't open.
I don't know HTML or bootstrap. Can You help me?

by the way, this is bootstrap 5, and I wrote it with the jinja template

Comment: Bootstrap requires jquery.

Comment: how can i add jquery

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` add this before the bootstrap CDN.

Comment: still dont working

Comment: look in the console (ctrl+shift+i). what does it say?

Comment: console is not returned any error

Comment: Can you show us your webpage?

Comment: give me five minute for you can see local website

Comment: https://repl.it/@ch1ck3n/stackvoerflow-answer-thing here you go!

Comment: Bootstrap 5 removes jQuery dependency. "Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you didn't import the right files.

the only imports required in bootstrap 5 is

`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

and

`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

here is a working repl:
https://repl.it/@ch1ck3n/stackvoerflow-answer-thing